# Dereferencing Rc<Vec<T>> confusion in Rust

Tags: rust, dereference

Why does the following code work?

```
use std::rc::Rc;
fn main () {
    let c = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let r = Rc::new(c);
    println!("{:?}", (**r)[0]);
}
```

I can understand it working with single deference (`println!("{:?}", (*r)[0]);`). But not able to understand it working with double-dereference too.

Comment: `Deref`-ception. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be easier to understand what happens once we build a function prototype around the expression `(**r)[0]`:

```
fn foo<T, U>(r: T) -> i32
where
    T: Deref<Target=U>,
    U: Deref<Target=[i32]>,
{
    (**r)[0]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bc1d1c74dd4ac67a718b2c459131a257&version=stable)

`Rc<T>`, as is typical for most smart containers in Rust, implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) so that it can be used as an ordinary reference to the underlying value. In turn, `Vec<T>` implements `Deref` so that it can be used as a slice (`Target = [T]`). The explicit dereferencing `*`, when performed twice, applies the two conversions in sequence.

Of course, usually you wouldn't need to do this, because `Vec` also implements the `Index` operator.

Answer (score 12):

Both, [Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) implements [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), whichs [`deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref)-method is called with the `*`.

```
let c = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

creates a [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) with the given elements with the [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html)-macro.

```
let r = Rc::new(c);
```

creates a [Reference counted Object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) from the Vector. The Vector is moved into the [RC](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html).

```
println!("{:?}", (**r)[0]);
```

This one is a bit more tricky: `*r` [dereferences](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-Deref) the Rc, so we get the underlying Vector. `*rc` [dereferences](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) the Vector as a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html). `slice[0]` [indexes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) the first element of the slice, which results in the first element `1`. `println!` finally prints the result.